# Comparing paired percentages with a constraint

Tags: paired-data, percentage, constraint

I would like to compare two variables, which are paired and both contain percentages. The sample size shall be large enough (>100), so I do not consider applying any nonparametric method. However, the data have a constraint: the summation of each variable across all samples is 100%. Meanwhile, the mean difference is always equal to 0, resulting in a non-significant finding, for example, when applying the paired t-test.

I carefully reviewed each paired datum and can see many large differences. However, because of the constraint, mathematically the mean difference must be 0. I consider calculating an absolute difference in each sample, and then just applying the one-sample t-test to see whether the average absolute difference is different from 0. Nonetheless, I am not sure whether this way is adequate, so would like to look for better suggestions here. Any advice will be appreciated.

Appendix: Example data set

```
   A       B
1.2958% 0.2754%
0.8976% 0.0571%
0.0014% 6.1195%
0.0001% 0.9360%
0.5965% 0.6148%
0.6451% 4.6125%
1.0589% 3.3716%
18.9387%    0.5680%
0.0156% 10.1050%
0.0002% 2.2976%
0.0001% 0.0464%
0.7307% 0.6812%
0.0297% 0.0359%
0.7700% 0.7283%
0.1866% 0.8086%
0.0004% 0.2417%
0.0008% 0.0036%
0.0030% 0.0036%
0.0552% 0.0600%
0.2201% 0.0346%
0.0002% 0.0002%
0.0161% 0.0000%
0.5429% 0.6927%
0.0786% 1.2733%
0.3617% 0.0124%
0.0632% 0.0013%
1.0303% 0.7299%
0.0161% 0.0000%
3.4283% 0.0038%
8.9082% 0.7318%
0.9987% 0.3195%
3.0034% 0.0000%
8.8592% 0.1024%
0.2318% 0.4429%
0.0001% 0.3637%
0.0002% 0.2599%
0.1285% 1.4598%
0.0179% 0.4668%
0.0034% 0.0001%
0.0004% 0.9446%
0.1250% 0.0167%
0.0763% 0.4332%
0.0370% 0.0142%
0.0001% 0.0045%
0.0000% 0.2600%
0.0001% 0.0180%
0.1727% 0.2488%
0.0597% 0.0001%
0.7820% 0.0000%
0.0010% 0.0001%
0.0002% 0.0006%
0.0002% 0.0008%
4.8509% 0.0178%
0.1843% 0.0396%
0.0013% 0.0286%
0.0422% 0.0000%
0.0015% 0.1448%
0.6003% 0.0890%
0.0007% 2.0618%
1.2511% 3.5741%
0.1090% 1.7009%
0.1524% 12.1599%
0.0001% 0.2743%
0.1195% 1.0287%
0.0967% 0.0168%
7.0878% 2.1494%
0.0581% 0.0148%
0.5725% 0.5404%
0.0521% 0.2784%
0.0674% 0.0556%
0.0518% 0.1621%
0.0004% 0.0037%
0.0697% 0.0319%
0.0002% 0.1879%
0.0390% 0.4081%
0.0465% 1.7749%
0.0067% 0.8970%
1.8057% 1.5860%
0.0001% 0.0000%
0.0001% 0.0003%
0.0002% 0.0000%
0.0001% 0.0001%
0.1865% 0.7606%
0.0005% 3.6864%
0.0585% 0.1753%
0.2531% 0.4169%
6.2940% 0.8392%
0.2351% 0.0010%
5.6931% 0.0013%
0.1386% 0.0869%
0.0004% 0.3024%
0.4398% 0.0037%
0.0002% 0.0460%
0.0008% 1.7725%
6.8872% 1.3745%
0.0179% 0.6480%
0.0002% 0.3746%
0.0144% 1.1539%
0.0005% 0.0001%
0.1142% 1.0996%
0.0003% 0.0001%
0.6861% 0.1615%
0.2226% 0.0000%
0.8919% 3.6944%
2.1051% 0.9582%
0.0002% 0.0005%
0.0041% 0.0489%
0.0007% 0.0000%
0.2124% 0.0001%
0.0009% 0.0000%
0.6785% 0.5488%
0.0002% 0.1792%
0.0003% 2.9151%
0.1376% 0.0001%
0.0001% 0.0002%
0.0002% 0.0174%
0.0794% 0.0673%
1.8886% 0.0164%
0.0322% 0.0036%
0.0789% 0.0665%
0.1467% 0.0076%
0.0799% 0.0652%
0.0782% 0.0005%
0.1427% 0.0958%
0.0007% 1.1472%
0.0015% 0.3929%
0.0004% 0.0013%
0.0000% 0.0024%
0.0001% 0.0515%
0.0199% 0.0621%
0.0199% 0.0510%
0.0001% 2.0921%
0.3919% 4.9532%
0.1051% 0.0263%
```

Comment: Can you give us a small sample of data to further clarify the problem?

Comment: I have appended an example data set for people who are interested in taking a look at it.

Comment: What about the raw count data - do you have that? Maybe try using a contingency table approach.